# Insert a condition if the date is not in my database on shiny

Tags: r, shiny

The shiny code below generates a graph for the days that are in `date2`, ie 01/07, 02/07 and 04/07. So far ok, however, as you can see on the calendar there are all other days that are enabled. Therefore, I would like to make some condition or something so that if I don't have the date in my database, the graph is generated considering this condition of the code.

```
 if (nrow(datas)<=2){
    abline(h=m,lwd=2) 
    points(0, m, col = "red", pch = 19, cex = 2, xpd = TRUE)
    text(.1,m+ .5, round(m,1), cex=1.1,pos=4,offset =1,col="black")}
```

So, my graph would have no points, just the line in `m`.

Executable code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)

function.test<-function(){
  
  df1 <- structure(
    list(date1= c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
         date2 = c("2021-07-01","2021-07-02","2021-07-04"),
         Category = c("ABC","ABC","ABC"),
         Week= c("Wednesday","Wednesday","Wednesday"),
         DR1 = c(4,1,0),
         DR01 = c(4,1,0), DR02= c(4,2,0),DR03= c(9,5,0),
         DR04 = c(5,4,0),DR05 = c(5,4,0),DR06 = c(5,4,0),DR07 = c(5,4,0),DR08 = c(5,4,0)),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
  
  
  
  return(df1)
}

f1 <- function(df1, dmda, CategoryChosse) {
  
  x<-df1 %>% select(starts_with("DR0"))
  
  x<-cbind(df1, setNames(df1$DR1 - x, paste0(names(x), "_PV")))
  PV<-select(x, date2,Week, Category, DR1, ends_with("PV"))
  
  med<-PV %>%
    group_by(Category,Week) %>%
    summarize(across(ends_with("PV"), median))
  
  SPV<-df1%>%
    inner_join(med, by = c('Category', 'Week')) %>%
    mutate(across(matches("^DR0\\d+$"), ~.x + 
                    get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV')),
                  .names = '{col}_{col}_PV')) %>%
    select(date1:Category, DR01_DR01_PV:last_col())
  
  SPV<-data.frame(SPV)
  
  mat1 <- df1 %>%
    filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
    select(starts_with("DR0")) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
    arrange(desc(row_number())) %>%
    mutate(cs = cumsum(value)) %>%
    filter(cs == 0) %>%
    pull(name)
  
  (dropnames <- paste0(mat1,"_",mat1, "_PV"))
  
  SPV <- SPV %>%
    filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
    select(-any_of(dropnames))
  
  if(length(grep("DR0", names(SPV))) == 0) {
    SPV[head(mat1,10)] <- NA_real_
  }
  
  datas <-SPV %>%
    filter(date2 == ymd(dmda)) %>%
    group_by(Category) %>%
    summarize(across(starts_with("DR0"), sum)) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols= -Category, names_pattern = "DR0(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
    mutate(name = readr::parse_number(name))
  colnames(datas)[-1]<-c("Days","Numbers")
  
  
  datas <- datas %>% 
    group_by(Category) %>% 
    slice((as.Date(dmda) - min(as.Date(df1$date1) [
      df1$Category == first(Category)])):max(Days)+1) %>%
    ungroup
  
  m<-df1 %>%
    group_by(Category,Week) %>%
    summarize(across(starts_with("DR1"), mean))
  
  m<-subset(m, Week == df1$Week[match(ymd(dmda), ymd(df1$date2))] & Category == CategoryChosse)$DR1
  
  maxrange <-  range(min(0, datas$Numbers, na.rm = TRUE), na.rm = TRUE)
  maxrange[2] <- maxrange[2] - (maxrange[2] %%10) + 35
  
  max<-max(0, datas$Days, na.rm = TRUE)+1
  
  plot(Numbers ~ Days,  xlim= c(0,max),  ylim= c(0,maxrange[2]),
       xaxs='i',data = datas,main = paste0(dmda, "-", CategoryChosse))
  
  if (nrow(datas)<=2){
    abline(h=m,lwd=2) 
    points(0, m, col = "red", pch = 19, cex = 2, xpd = TRUE)
    text(.1,m+ .5, round(m,1), cex=1.1,pos=4,offset =1,col="black")}
  
  else if(any(table(datas$Numbers) >= 3) & length(unique(datas$Numbers)) == 1){
    yz <- unique(datas$Numbers)
    lines(c(0,datas$Days), c(yz, datas$Numbers), lwd = 2)
    points(0, yz, col = "red", pch = 19, cex = 2, xpd = TRUE)
    text(.1,yz+ .5,round(yz,1), cex=1.1,pos=4,offset =1,col="black")}
  
  else{
    mod <- nls(Numbers ~ b1*Days^2+b2,start = list(b1 = 0,b2 = 0),data = datas, algorithm = "port")
    new.data <- data.frame(Days = with(datas, seq(min(Days),max(Days),len = 45)))
    new.data <- rbind(0, new.data)
    lines(new.data$Days,predict(mod,newdata = new.data),lwd=2)
    coef<-coef(mod)[2]
    points(0, coef, col="red",pch=19,cex = 2,xpd=TRUE)
    text(.99,coef + 1,max(0, round(coef,1)), cex=1.1,pos=4,offset =1,col="black")
  }
  
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                          br(),
                          
                          tabPanel("",
                                   sidebarLayout(
                                     sidebarPanel(
                                       
                                       uiOutput("date"),
                                       uiOutput("mycode"),

                                       br(),
                                       
                                       
                                     ),
                                     
                                     mainPanel(
                                       tabsetPanel(
                                         tabPanel("", plotOutput("graph",width = "100%", height = "600")
                                         )
                                       ),
                                     ))
                          )))


server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  data <- reactive(function.test())
  
  output$date <- renderUI({
    req(data())
    all_dates <- seq(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-01-15'), by = "day")
    disabled <- as.Date(setdiff(all_dates, as.Date(data()$date2)), origin = "1970-01-01")
    dateInput(input = "date2", 
              label = h4("Data"),
              min = min(data()$date2),
              value = min(data()$date2),
              format = "dd-mm-yyyy",
              datesdisabled = disabled)
    
  })
  
  output$mycode <- renderUI({
    req(input$date2)
    df1 <- data()
    df2 <- df1[as.Date(df1$date2) %in% input$date2,]
    selectInput("code", label = h4("Category"),choices=unique(df2$Category))
  })
  
  output$graph <- renderPlot({
    req(input$date2,input$code)
    f1(data(),as.character(input$date2),as.character(input$code))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: As `datas` might be null when selected date may not exist in the dateframe `df1`, you need to define how you want to plot it.

Comment: Thanks @YBS for reply! So, do you think I should adjust my function before going to Shiny? I would just like that dates that do not have in `date2` of my database use the condition `if (nrow(datas)<=2) ` of my code

Comment: No graph comes out when you use that, if date is not present in df1 as datas is NULL.

Comment: I understood! But if by chance I have the dates in `date2` in my database, but my DR0 columns don't have information, that is, NA, then I can adjust this, right?

Comment: My suggestion is if your selected date is not in the database, do not call the function f1.  Instead, plot something (whatever plot you want) on the server side - which is what I was doing in the answer I had posted.

Comment: Ah now it's more clear to me, sorry YBS for so many questions

Answer (score 0):

The following addresses when `date2` is prior to `date1` or `input$date2` does not exist in the database.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)

##  No Data Plot when NULL data is supplied
NoDataPlot <- function(mysel=1){
  df <- data.frame()
  p <- ggplot(df) + geom_point() + xlim(0, 10) + ylim(0, 10) +
    annotate("text", x=4.1, y=5.3, size=40, col="red", label="(" ) +
    annotate("text", x=5, y=5.6, size=12, col="red", label="o  o" ) +
    annotate("text", x=5.9, y=5.3, size=40, col="red", label=")" ) +
    annotate("text", x=5, y=5.1, size=10, col="red", label="|" ) +
    geom_segment(aes(x = 4.7, xend = 5.3, y = 4.7, yend = 4.7), size=1.5, color="red") +
    {if (mysel==1) annotate("text", x=5, y=3.7, size=10, col="red", label="No Data")} +
    {if (mysel==2) annotate("text", x=5, y=3.7, size=10, col="red", label="Date2 before Date1")}
  p
}

function.test<-function(){

  df1 <- structure(
    list(date1 = c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
         date2 = c("2021-06-25","2021-06-30","2021-06-30","2021-07-01","2021-07-01"),
         Category = c("FDE", "FDE","ABC","FDE","ABC"),
         Week= c("Tuesday", "Wednesday","Wednesday","Friday","Friday"),
         DR1 = c(2,4,1,6,3),
         DR01 = c(2,4,1,4,3), DR02= c(2,4,2,6,2), DR03= c(2,9,5,4,7),
         DR04 = c(2,5,4,3,2), DR05 = c(2,5,4,5,4),
         DR06 = c(2,2,4,3,2), DR07 = c(2,2,5,4,4),
         DR08 = c(2,3,4,5,4), DR09 = c(2,2,3,4,4)),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

  return(df1)
}

  f1 <- function(df1, dmda, CategoryChosse) {

    x<-df1 %>% select(starts_with("DR0"))

    x<-cbind(df1, setNames(df1$DR1 - x, paste0(names(x), "_PV")))
    PV<-select(x, date2,Week, Category, DR1, ends_with("PV"))

    med<-PV %>%
      group_by(Category,Week) %>%
      summarize(across(ends_with("PV"), median))

    SPV<-df1%>%
      inner_join(med, by = c('Category', 'Week')) %>%
      mutate(across(matches("^DR0\\d+$"), ~.x +
                      get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV')),
                    .names = '{col}_{col}_PV')) %>%
      select(date1:Category, DR01_DR01_PV:last_col())

    SPV<-data.frame(SPV)

    mat1 <- df1 %>%
      filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
      select(starts_with("DR0")) %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
      arrange(desc(row_number())) %>%
      mutate(cs = cumsum(value)) %>%
      filter(cs == 0) %>%
      pull(name)

    (dropnames <- paste0(mat1,"_",mat1, "_PV"))

    SPV <- SPV %>%
      filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
      select(-any_of(dropnames))

    datas<-SPV %>%
      filter(date2 == ymd(dmda)) %>%
      group_by(Category) %>%
      summarize(across(starts_with("DR0"), sum)) %>%
      pivot_longer(cols= -Category, names_pattern = "DR0(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
      mutate(name = readr::parse_number(name))
    colnames(datas)[-1]<-c("Days","Numbers")

    datas <- datas %>%
      group_by(Category) %>%
      slice((as.Date(dmda) - min(as.Date(df1$date1) [
        df1$Category == first(Category)])):max(Days)+1) %>%
      ungroup

    plot(Numbers ~ Days,  xlim= c(0,45), ylim= c(0,30),
         xaxs='i',data = datas,main = paste0(dmda, "-", CategoryChosse))

    model <- nls(Numbers ~ b1*Days^2+b2,start = list(b1 = 0,b2 = 0),data = datas, algorithm = "port")

    new.data <- data.frame(Days = with(datas, seq(min(Days),max(Days),len = 45)))
    new.data <- rbind(0, new.data)
    lines(new.data$Days,predict(model,newdata = new.data),lwd=2)
    coef<-coef(model)[2]
    points(0, coef, col="red",pch=19,cex = 2,xpd=TRUE)
    text(.99,coef + 1,max(0, round(coef,1)), cex=1.1,pos=4,offset =1,col="black")

  }


ui <- fluidPage(

  ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                          br(),

                          tabPanel("",
                                   sidebarLayout(
                                     sidebarPanel(

                                       uiOutput("date"),
                                       uiOutput("mycode"),
                                       br(),


                                     ),

                                     mainPanel(
                                       tabsetPanel(
                                         tabPanel("", plotOutput("graph",width = "100%", height = "600")
                                         )
                                       ),
                                     ))
                          )))


server <- function(input, output,session) {

  data <- reactive(function.test())

  output$date <- renderUI({
    req(data())
    all_dates <- seq(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-01-15'), by = "day")
    disabled <- as.Date(setdiff(all_dates, as.Date(data()$date2)), origin = "1970-01-01")
    dateInput(input = "date2",
              label = h4("Data"),
              min = min(data()$date2),
              max = max(data()$date2),
              value = min(data()$date2),
              format = "dd-mm-yyyy",
              datesdisabled = disabled)

  })

  output$mycode <- renderUI({
    req(input$date2)
    df1 <- data()
    df2 <- df1[as.Date(df1$date2) %in% input$date2,]
    selectInput("code", label = h4("Code"),choices=unique(df2$Category))
  })

  output$graph <- renderPlot({
    req(input$date2)

    if (sum(as.Date(data()$date2) %in% as.Date(input$date2))<1) { ## dates not in dataframe
      myplot <- NoDataPlot()
    }else {
      req(input$code)
      tmp1 <- data() %>% dplyr::filter(date2  == input$date2, Category == input$code)
      if (as.Date(unique(tmp1$date1)) > as.Date(input$date2))  myplot <- NoDataPlot(2)  ## date2 prior to date1
      else myplot <- f1(data(),as.character(input$date2),as.character(input$code))
    }

    myplot
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Hi YBS thanks for replying. In fact, my intention is only days after `date2`, that is, it will include some days in July (just not 01/07, 02/07 and 04/07 because I have these days on `date2`), August, September, October and so on. Will always use that condition that I showed there.